# Python script executing Jython script

Tags: python, jython

I am new to both Python and Jython. I am just wondering if is possible to use Python to execute a Jython script and get its result.

The reason is the code was previously done by another person and I do not want to go changing or messing with every single thing that has compatibility issue with Jython. because I just need to pass some data to a Java class and receive its return result.

I try using subprocess but i kept getting a error stating (The system cannot find the file specified)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['Jython', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: How do you run test.py with Jython from the command-line? Does it succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible problems here:

- change `Jython` to `jython` as the terminal/python are case sensitive.
- specify the absolute path to your test script `'/{PATH TO TEST SCRPIT}/test.py'`